# How to accept deposits with required quantity of tokens?

Tags: smart-contract, deposit

What are the best practices for setting a minimum deposit amount for a contract?

Answer (score 2):

You can store the minimum value in a singleton via a public method that requires authentication, use the `asset` struct for your method, and assert that the amount exceeds your minimum value.

Example:

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/asset.hpp>
#include <eosiolib/singleton.hpp>

using eosio::contract;
using eosio::asset;
using eosio::singleton;
using eosio::print;

class min_tokens : public contract {
    public:
        min_tokens(account_name n) : contract(n), tokens_store(_self, _self) {}

        void min(account_name account, uint64_t min) {
            require_auth(_self);
            require_auth(account);
            tokens_store.set(min, _self);
        }

        void something(account_name account, asset tokens ) {
            require_auth(account);
            _requirements(tokens);
            print("Success!");
        }

    private:
        singleton<N(tokens), uint64_t> tokens_store;

        void _requirements(const asset& tokens) {
            eosio_assert(tokens.amount >= tokens_store.get(), "You need to send more tokens");
        }
};

EOSIO_ABI(min_tokens, (something)(min))
```

Comment: Is `void min` not guaranteed to assert unless `_self` is equal to `account`? If not how would the permissions look like for executing that command?

Comment: @PhillipHamnett-EOS42 my thinking was that `_self` can let `account` use their `active` permission with `cleos set account permission <contract_creator> active <json>` in case others besides the creator should be allowed to set a minimum threshold too